# Why is my MacbookPro 2018 working on OpenGL 2.1?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, macbook-pro, opengl

I am a student in Computer Science and for classes we are working with OpenGL.
My issue is that I can't run any program because of my OpenGL driver version.

Graphic card : Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 655
Driver OpenGL : 2.1 INTEL-12.4.7

After some researches I've found that MacOS supports OpenGL 4.1 So, why my Macbook Pro from 2018 isn't running 4.1 version but 2.1?
Is there a way to upgrade/update the version?

Thank you all for your help, I am very desperate

Comment: Apple has depreciated OpenGL and OpenCL in MacOS in favor of Metal. Nevertheless, according [to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823), you should have OpenGL 4.1 and OpenCL 1.2. It's not possible on Apple computers to upgrade OpenGL and OpenCL versions, as they are closely related to the hardware.

Comment: Yes I should have 4.1 but my computer uses 2.1. Is my computer wrongly configured?

Comment: Or it's not a Macbook Pro 2018.